# Best way to get JNIEnv performance?

Tags: java-native-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android, jnienv

Ive been struggling to find a fast/performant way to pass data between C# and Java.

My initial and unique approach up to now was using JNIEnv.

A simple test case of a Java class Adder:

```
void add(float[] arr1, float[] arr2, float[] res)
{
        for (int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = arr1[i]+arr2[i];
        }
}
```

And on C# side:

```
public void Add(float[] arr1, float[] arr2, float[] res)
{
        var methodHandle = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "add","([F[F[F)V");

        IntPtr arr1Handle = JNIEnv.NewArray(arr1);
        IntPtr arr2Handle = JNIEnv.NewArray(arr2);
        IntPtr resHandle = JNIEnv.NewArray(res);

        JNIEnv.CopyArray (arr1, arr1Handle);
        JNIEnv.CopyArray (arr2, arr2Handle);

        JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(Handle, methodHandle, new JValue(arr1Handle), new JValue(arr2Handle), new JValue(resHandle));

        JNIEnv.CopyArray (resHandle, res);
}
```

For the same physical device: With float[] arrays of size 1million, profiling this Add() method in c# holds values between 200-500ms! A note to say that if i run the same test in an Android native Eclipse project, the call to the function takes 20-50ms.

If you need to handle large arrays of data like images, matrixes, for real time requirements ... then this becomes unusable.

Can anyone advise another way of binding data to Java or another approach within JNIEnv?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should be looking into direct NIO buffers on the Java side. Those point to native data buffers that can be accessed directly in C# as well without needing to pin them or anything...

Comment: Thank you so much Samuel, great hint! Worked like a treat. I am partially (almost fully) happy because i only get a 50% improvement in performance... but anyway its better than before. In your experience shall we expect that kind of improvement or it should be even better?

Comment: Make sure to call only once all the JNI functions, other than "CallVoidMethod" obviously, and cache everything instead. That should help.

Comment: Thanks for your hints Samuel. I reformulated my "benchmarking" app and considering all the steps for the process, using JNIEnv.New/CopyArray() is actually faster. When i mentioned speed up before unfortunately i was missing all the Buffer.Put/Get() operations that are as costly as JNIEnv functions.